# How to Troubleshoot EnumWindows() Python Callback Failure

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ctypes

### The Problem

I'm trying to use [EnumWindows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) from Python (with ctypes). I appear to be having some trouble with my callback function, though it only happens after the callback is invoked over 1K (ballpark figure) times.

For example:

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes

WNDENUMPROC = CFUNCTYPE(wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT)
EnumWindows = windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindows.argtypes = [ WNDENUMPROC, wintypes.INT ]
EnumWindows.restype = wintypes.BOOL

def py_callback( hwnd, lparam ):
    print('{}'.format(hwnd))
    return True

EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC(py_callback),0)
```

When I run this (using [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) zero, python 3.5), the callback is invoked successfully many times. I see the window handle integers print()ed.
At some point, though, it fails:

```
...
3740010
4597178
65918
196762
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 13, in <module>
    EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC(py_callback),0)
ValueError: Procedure probably called with not enough arguments (5043578 bytes missing)
```

The "bytes missing" value changes every time.

### Python Distro

I have a micro install of Python that's deployed to a bunch of production machines (or else I might just update the Python distro). It's WinPython Zero 3.5.2.

The script fails on my production distro. I tried it against the latest 3.6.2 WinPython, and the results are the same.

I can run this same script with Python 3.6 (Anaconda) without errors.

I need to figure out what's going wrong here so that if I need to fix clients, I can make the smallest change possible.

### Troubleshooting

Most of the references to this error message "called with not enough arguments" advise to double-check the calling convention, but the callback works many times before it fails. I'm skeptical of this.

Are there some underlying dependencies that I could look at that could account for the different behavior I see between Python distros?

It seems to fail at the end of the window list. If I run the script from a working distro and a bad distro in close succession, I get the same number of emitted handles.

Any ideas as to why this would work for a while and then fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in your script:

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes

# LPARAM is not necessarily INT-sized.  Use the correct type.
# CALLBACK is __stdcall, so WINFUNCTYPE should be used instead of CFUNCTYPE,
# which is __cdecl calling convention
WNDENUMPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.HWND, wintypes.LPARAM)

# WinDLL should be used instead of windll.  Setting argtypes/restype on the windll
# common instance could affect other modules.
EnumWindows = WinDLL('user32').EnumWindows
EnumWindows.argtypes = WNDENUMPROC, wintypes.LPARAM  # LPARAM not INT
EnumWindows.restype = wintypes.BOOL

# Using a decorator keeps a reference to the callback.
# Building it in the EnumWindows call means it is released after the call.
# Not a problem in EnumWindows case since it isn't needed after the call
# returns, but for functions that register a callback and return immediately
# it is a problem.
@WNDENUMPROC
def py_callback( hwnd, lparam ):
    print(hwnd)
    return True

EnumWindows(py_callback,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations. I think it was the `CFUNCTYPE()` that I'd copied from semi-related code example that was causing the problem.